# Spark standalone cluster port related issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, apache-spark-standalone

I am deploying spark app through standalone cluster. I have one master and 2 slaves.

I am testing my cluster. I have application .jar copied everywhere at the same location.

I have observed following issue:

**on Master**

```
bin/spark-submit  --class ***** --master spark://master:6066  --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true --deploy-mode cluster  --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1   ******.jar
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign
>   requested address: Service 'Driver' failed after 16 retries! Consider
>   explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'Driver' (for
>   example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing
>   spark.port.maxRetries.

**on slave1**

```
bin/spark-submit  --class ***** --master spark://master:6066  --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true --deploy-mode cluster  --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1   ******.jar
```

Job executes

**on slave2**

```
bin/spark-submit  --class ***** --master spark://master:6066  --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true --deploy-mode cluster  --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1   ******.jar
```

Job executes

But I submit more than one job on a slave, only the first job executes.

**On Master**

```
bin/spark-submit  ******.jar  --class ******
```

Job executes occupies full resources on both the slaves and does not consider the remaining params

However, If I put the jar at the end of command, the above mentioned first 3 scenarios occur.

I have done cluster config using
http://spark.praveendeshmane.co.in/spark/spark-1-6-1-cluster-mode-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04.jsp on AWS ec2 instances.

I want to execute multiple jobs simultaneously.